# How can I customize my graph figures in matplotlib.figure.Figure such as changing marker size?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, canvas, customization

The following code is in my matplotlib graphing class that I embedded into tkinter, and it creates the desired figure (shape of graph is correct):

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

fig = Figure(figsize=(12, 10), dpi=100)
fig.add_subplot(111).scatter(df['A'], df['B'])

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.parent)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

The problem I'm having is styling the graph. How do I make the marker size significantly smaller? How do I customize the library to make it styled the way I want?

Edit: [Image of how graph currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSxMJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `s` parameter of scatter?  [See examples here](https://www.science-emergence.com/Articles/How-to-increase-the-size-of-scatter-points-in-matplotlib-/)

```
fig.add_subplot(111).scatter(df['A'], df['B'], s=SOME_NUM)
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you!